# Matching string from arraylist where the string is the result of concatenation from the arraylist

Tags: java, android, json, string-matching

Im trying to figure out the best possible way to match the string (called as **userInput**) where the string is the result of the concatenation from other few string (arraylist or array which in the example i called as **approved**)

```
ArrayList<String> approved = new ArrayList<>();
approved.add("abc");
approved.add("def");
approved.add("ghi");
approved.add("def jkl ggwp my life"); //repeated elements (abc,jkl)
approved.add("jkl");
approved.add("mno");
approved.add("pqr");
approved.add("stu vwx");
approved.add("yz");
```

I'll just use this arraylist (above) for the sake of explaining my difficulty.But,in real world,i have a

```
    -fixed arraylist which wont have dynamic elements (the elements in the arraylist wont change)
    -arraylist with more than 6000 elements
    -elements in the arraylist contains multiple word e.g ("stu vwx")
    -repeated elements but concatenated with another string in the arraylist
```

The program shall **return true** if the following is the **userInput**

```
userInput = "abc def";
userInput = "stu vwx yz"; //they can combine with another element as a whole
userInput = "ghi"; //it doesnt have to combine with another element
userInput = "vwx yz"; //they can split the arraylist elements with whitespace only and concatenate it with another element
```

However,the program shall **return false** if the following is the **userInput**

```
userInput = "yza"; //obviously it doesnt match anything
userInput = "ghi jk"; //doesnt match the concatenated string (ghi and jkl)
userInput = "pqr stu v"; //it can split the element with whitespace,but it has to take the whole word
userInput = "def abc"; //the order are important
```

Im thinking of splitting the **userInput** to get **firstWord** and **lastWord** since the order are important.Then,use **contains** to find the index of them within the arraylist.

Let's say

```
String userInput = "def ghi jkl mno";
//so,the firstWord and lastWord will be
firstWord = "def";
lastWord = "mno";
```

From here,the **.contains()** will do its job and return multiple index of the elements which have the string **firstWord** and **lastWord** (since the **firstWord** occured multiple times in the arraylist),it will be configured to return the possible matches in another array.

```
firstWordPossibleIndex[] = {1,4};
lastWordPossibleIndex[] = {6};
```

Since the order is important,the logic here is that the **firstWordPossibleIndex** should contains lower value than the **lastWordPossibleIndex**,so,if there's any bigger value,it can be removed because the string provided would be invalid.

After implementing that logic,it should start matching the next index from the **firstWordPossibleIndex** to the **lastWordPossibleIndex**

Meaning in this case,it would check the second word in the **userInput** and try to match with the elements with index of 2 and 5 (since **firstWordPossibleIndex** is 1 and 4)

It would check until the **lastwordPossibleIndex** and if all the words are in order according to the arraylist,it will return true.

With this,i still have trouble with *matching the string where it is concatenated* with part of another string. Do you have any idea to solve this ?

Are there any library to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WhatSoEver{

    static int order;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> approved = new ArrayList<>();
        approved.add("abc");
        approved.add("def");
        approved.add("ghi");
        approved.add("def jkl ggwp my life");
        approved.add("jkl");
        approved.add("mno");
        approved.add("pqr");
        approved.add("stu vwx");
        approved.add("yz");

        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "abc def")); // true
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "stu vwx yz")); // true
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "ghi")); // true
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "vwx yz")); // true        

        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "yza")); // false
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "ghi jk")); //false
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "pqr stu v")); //false
        System.out.println(isValid(approved, "def abc")); //false

    }

    public static boolean isValid(List<String> approved, String userInput){
        order=0;
        for(String word : userInput.split(" ")){
            if(!containsWord(approved, word)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean containsWord(List<String> approved, String word){
         for(int i=0; i<approved.size(); i++){
            for(String subS : approved.get(i).split(" ")){
               if(word.equals(subS) && (i+1)>order){
                      order=i;
                      return true;
               }
            }
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should split entries like "def jlk ggwp my life" into each parts  (5 in this case) and add them to the list separately. Then, split the user's inputs by spaces and save it into an array and just do

approved.contains (element of input array)

If all the elements in the array are present in the approved arraylist, then return true. If any of them are not in the approved list, return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> approved = new ArrayList<>();
    approved.add("abc");
    approved.add("def");
    approved.add("ghi");
    approved.add("def jkl ggwp my life"); //repeated elements (abc,jkl)
    approved.add("jkl");
    approved.add("mno");
    approved.add("pqr");
    approved.add("stu vwx");
    approved.add("yz");

    String[] userInput ={"abc def","stu vwx yz","ghi","vwx yz","yza","ghi jk","pqr stu v","def abc"};
    for(String str: userInput){
        System.out.println(str+"\t"+check(str,approved));
    }
}

public static boolean check(String userInput, ArrayList<String> list){
    String joined = String.join(" ", list)+" ";        
    return joined.contains(userInput+" ");
}
```